# ROS apriltags3 isntalling with warning - preventing package identification

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ros

I am attempting to get ROS to run with the april tags library for robotics research. I am fairly new to ros and dont really know where to start with this troubleshooting.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4
ROS distro: melodic

I have followed the quick start tutorial from the april tag's [github page](https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltag_ros)

everything seems to happen without a hiccup until the catkin build command. The packages are found and all the dependencies are successfully installed. Then the packages claim to be successfully installed after the catkin build command is complete.

```
robertslab@robertslab-HP-Pavilion-Gaming-Laptop-15-cx0xxx:~/april_3$ catkin build
------------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:             [env] /opt/ros/melodic
Workspace:                   /home/robertslab/april_3
------------------------------------------------------------
Build Space:        [exists] /home/robertslab/april_3/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/robertslab/april_3/devel
Install Space:      [unused] /home/robertslab/april_3/install
Log Space:         [missing] /home/robertslab/april_3/logs
Source Space:       [exists] /home/robertslab/april_3/src
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
------------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        None
------------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       None
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
------------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
------------------------------------------------------------
Workspace configuration appears valid.

NOTE: Forcing CMake to run for each package.
------------------------------------------------------------
[build] Found '2' packages in 0.0 seconds.                 
[build] Updating package table.                            
Starting  >>> catkin_tools_prebuild                        
Finished  <<< catkin_tools_prebuild                [ 1.5 seconds ]
Starting  >>> apriltag                                     
___________________________________________________________
Warnings   << apriltag:install /home/robertslab/april_3/logs/apriltag/build.install.000.log
cp: cannot create regular file '/home/robertslab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages': No such file or directory
cd /home/robertslab/april_3/build/apriltag; catkin build --get-env apriltag | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/make install; cd -
...........................................................
Finished  <<< apriltag                             [ 7.0 seconds ]
Starting  >>> apriltag_ros                                 
Finished  <<< apriltag_ros                         [ 15.2 seconds ]
[build] Summary: All 3 packages succeeded!                 
[build]   Ignored:   None.                                 
[build]   Warnings:  1 packages succeeded with warnings.   
[build]   Abandoned: None.                                 
[build]   Failed:    None.                                 
[build] Runtime: 23.7 seconds total.                       
[build] Note: Workspace packages have changed, please re-source setup files to use them.
```

Can someone please explain this warning.

Additionally, when I start Ros core and to a package search there is no April tag package installed and I am not sure why or how to install the package to Ros.

I have resourced the setup.bash file like the output says and april tags still does not show up in the rospack list output.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well this warning is quite self explanatory in which it is not able to copy some file to directory. I think it is looking for Python source directory which is not found.

apriltag_ros is dependent on april_tag these are two different packages.

As [this package](http://wiki.ros.org/apriltag_ros) is officially on ROS Melodic so you can install it by:

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-apriltag-ros
```

This will take care of all the dependencies needed and builds the project.

You can check the installtion directory by:

```
roscd apriltag_ros
pwd
```